# Controls are not positioning correctly when displaying validation summary on top of web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I am getting weird problem in using custom validator function  in asp.net page and  showing validation summary on the top of web page using CSS Styles.....

and this is the screen shot before clicking the button submit changes [image]

after submitting the page the validation summary is displayed on top but controls positon is changing like this 
[image]

and this is my code for

```
    <div id="validationSummaryHolder" class="validationSummaryHolder">
            <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="valsErrors" ValidationGroup="TestValidation" DisplayMode="BulletList"
                CssClass="validationsummary" HeaderText="<div class='validationheader'>Please correct the following:</div>" />        
        </div>
```

and this is my css styles for validation summary

Css Styles for validation summary

```
.validationheader 
{
background-color: white;
color:green;
height: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b08b34;
padding-top: 3px;
}
.validationsummary 
{
border: 1px solid #b08b34;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin:5px 0 20px 0px;
font-size:12px;
width:99%;
}
.validationsummary ul 
{
padding-top: 1px;
font-size: 12px;
color:#982b12;
}
.validationsummary ul li 
{
padding: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

I have  placed all controls in individual divs and mentioned type of positon for all controls  is **Relative** ..

I don't know why I am getting this weird thing,
 Do i need to set fixed height and width for total page ?
would any one pls help on this
Many thanks In advance....

Comment: Sorry i'm a bit confused. What effect are you expecting. The way the validation summary is behavin gseems reasonable to me (though not elegant admittedly)

Comment: @CrabBucket I am getting validation summary on the top itself that'S fine . But when i am   displaying validation summary is on the top the remaining control positions are changed automatically I don't know why i am getting like this.....

Comment: Erm - becuase it's displayed as a css block so the display stacks vertically. Really there is nowhere else for it to go. I guess you code try floating it but that would look pretty weird IMHO. You're best bet is not to use the validation summary or place it elsewhere like at the bottom (again odd). What's your desired outcome - how do you evisage the display

Answer (score 0):

Check the width of

```
<div id="validationSummaryHolder" class="validationSummaryHolder">
```

It is not likely the the validation summary's insides are causing anything of their own accord since they are contained in that div, but maybe the containing div is stretching or shrinking the page. Also some html in the question would help. If you can't paraphrase the html here, another option would be to show the wire frame of the page with and without the validation summary and the answer should be clear at that point what is happening.